# How to restrict allowed sub-entities in table referencing super-entity based on a type code

Tags: database-design, relations

I'm working on my first db architecture for a platform containing several user types and that can exchange assets between them. There are also several transaction types, but each transaction type accepts specific types of sender and recipient.

In order to avoid creating several transaction tables for each possible permutation of user type and asset type, I'm leaning towards using a super-type for users as well as for transactions, and keeping separate sub-type tables with the columns specific to each type. This way I can keep all sender-recipient data in a single table. This would look something like this:

[image]

The problem I see is that I can't restrict sender and recipient user types for each transaction type.

The most obvious solution is to move sender/recipient columns to each transaction type and associate them directly to the correct user sub-types. Once again, the problem with this approach is that I have to create extra transaction types for each allowed permutation (e.g. transaction_type_a from user_type_a to user_type_a, transaction_type_a from user_type_a to user_type_b, etc...).

Is there any other solution to impose the user type restriction on my transactions while avoiding creating tables for each transaction permutation? Or should I stick with this approach and apply validation checks elsewhere?

Comment: Even before you allow users to have transactions, there's already room for inconsistency in both user definitions and transaction definitions. Your user super type table `app_users` references the user type table `ref_user_types`, and so do the subtype tables `users_type_a`, `users_type_b` etc. However, based on this model, it should be possible to have a row in `users_type_a` reference type A and its parent row in `app_users` reference type B, which, if I understand correctly, should in fact be disallowed. Same goes for transactions. I think this issue is similar to what you are asking about.

Comment: @AndriyM You're right, I totally missed that. Do I even need to repeat the `type` column in both tables?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896831/how-to-implement-referential-integrity-in-subtypes